# Convert date value of cell to first day of month of date from another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'd set formula to a cell that makes its date value always the first day of the month of another cell - regardless of which day of the month is set as the date value in said other cell.

Is that possible with a formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is not the answer you are looking for, then edit your question and explain with examples what you are after...

```
=EOMONTH(A46,-1)+1
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thx!